# Could not find an edit version on App Store Connect. Try using '--use_live_version true'

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins, app-store-connect, fastlane

Error Jenkins when build and I got this error below.

```
[16:58:58]: Could not find an edit version on App Store Connect. Try using '--use_live_version true'

[16:58:58]: Couldn't download already existing screenshots from App Store Connect.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first log said, try set it true :

```
deliver(
  submit_for_review: true,
  force: true,
  metadata_path: "./metadata"
)
```

Also there is a similar [thread](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13522) here.

Add: `require 'open-uri'` at the beginning of `.../deliver/lib/deliver/download_screenshots.rb`